# Python argparse toggle flags

Tags: python, argparse

Is there any way in argparse to parse flags like `[+-]a,b,c,d`?

```
foo.py +s -b
```

should store True in the `dest` of `s` and False in the `dest` of `b`, much like done by the Windows `attrib` or the Linux `chmod`.

Currently, I am using 2 separate arguments `+s` and `-s` with `store_true` and `store_false`, respectively. But it creates an ugly help with it listing each flag twice (+a & -a)

Another workaround would be to manually parse the extended arg with regex (which somehow seems a lot easier and use custom description, *but* before doing that I just wanted to look around if there was anything using which I could perform the same thing using argparse itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by passing both `-s` and `+s` to a single `add_argument` call, and using a custom action:

```
class ToggleAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, ns, values, option):
        setattr(ns, self.dest, bool("-+".index(option[0])))
ap = ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='-+')
ap.add_argument('-s', '+s', action=ToggleAction, nargs=0)

ap.parse_args(['+s'])
Namespace(s=True)

ap.parse_args(['-s'])
Namespace(s=False)
```

Comment: Great, somehow I thought `action` would be the key but missed over defining an Action class.