# Python argparse --toggle --no-toggle flag

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a straightforward way to use `--toggle` and `--no-toggle` flags with Python's argparse?

Right now I'm using something similar to the following:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--toggle',
                    action='store_true',
                    dest='toggle')
parser.add_argument('--no-toggle',
                    action='store_true',
                    default=True,
                    dest='notoggle')

options = parser.parse_args([])
```

I'm just manually parsing out the possibilities in a long if chain, but it would be nice if there was a way to tidy this up and have the state immediately stored in one destination by the parser, e.g. `options.toggle`. Is this feasible and if so, how?

A somewhat related answer is [Python argparse toggle flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11510627/4117209) however I'm interested in using `--no-` as the longopts `store_false` toggle prefix (similar to the `-` shortopts toggle prefix outlined in the aforementioned link).

Comment: After parsing what do you do with `options.toggle` and `options.notoggle`? Is there some logical relation - e.g. one negates the other; over rides it?   Can the user give both arguments, in either order.  So far the only connection is in name similarity.  There isn't any feature in `argparse` like this, in part because there aren't any common usage patterns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python argparse, is it possible to have paired --no-something/--something arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234258/in-python-argparse-is-it-possible-to-have-paired-no-something-something-arg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not do the same as the post you linked to??

```
import argparse

class NegateAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, ns, values, option):
        setattr(ns, self.dest, option[2:4] != 'no')

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('--toggle', '--no-toggle', dest='toggle', action=NegateAction, nargs=0)
```

Then if the flag has `no` at the beginning it is set to False:

```
>>> ap.parse_args(['--toggle'])
Namespace(toggle=True)
>>> options = ap.parse_args(['--no-toggle'])
>>> options.toggle
False
```

Answer (score 10):

Arguments can use the same `dest`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--toggle',
                    action='store_const',
                    default = 'unknown',
                    const = 'yes',  # const=True also works
                    dest='toggle')
parser.add_argument('--no-toggle',
                    action='store_const',
                    const = 'no',   # or False
                    dest='toggle')
```

This produces:

```
In [60]: parser.parse_args([])    # none
Out[60]: Namespace(toggle='unknown')
In [61]: parser.parse_args(['--tog'])
Out[61]: Namespace(toggle='yes')
In [62]: parser.parse_args(['--no-tog'])
Out[62]: Namespace(toggle='no')
In [63]: parser.parse_args(['--no-tog','--tog'])  # more than one
Out[63]: Namespace(toggle='yes')
```

I used `store_const` rather than `store_true` and `store_false` to make the 3 alternatives clear.  `store_true` is just `store_const` with `const=True` and `default=False`.

If you define a `store_true` and `store_false` pair, it is hard to distinguish between the no argument case and `--no-toggle` case.  `--no-toggle` doesn't do anything significant, unless it follows a `--toggle` argument.

If you need to define a large set of these pairs, you can easily define a helper function, which takes a couple of the parameters, and creates the pair of arguments.