# Argparse: mutually exclusive groups with defaults

Tags: python, argparse

Maybe there was an answer to one of the similar questions, but I couldn't find it.

What I need.

I have a table to read from: table with most recent data (fast), table with data for one day (day).

I want to read from day-table by default and from fast-table if I provide an argument -f in the command line.

Then I have defaults for each argument. 
So if I don't provide any arguments ("-s" or "-f"), I want to use "day" with the default value.
If I use something like "-s 20161001" or "-f 1452557323", I want to use that value.
If use "-f", I want to use "-f" default value.

All I have right now is:

```
table_choice = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

table_choice.add_argument(
    '-s', '--day-table',
    dest='day',
    help='day table data',
    default="path/" + day(),
)

table_choice.add_argument(
    '-f', '--fast-table',
    dest='fast',
    help='fast table data',
    default=fast(),
)
```

But sadly it doesn't work like I want. 
"script -f" returns:

```
Script: error: argument -f/--fast-table: expected one argument
```

Only works if I have provided a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nargs='?'`, then you get a 3 way action - the default, a constant, or the value.

```
table_choice.add_argument(
    '-f', '--fast-table',
    dest='fast',
    help='fast table data',
    default=fast(),
    nargs='?',
    const='value_if_noarg'
)
```

This `nargs` plays nicely with mutually exclusive groups (including the 'required' one).

By making the group `required`, you will have to use either `-s` or `-f`.  Omit the `required=True` is you want the option of using neither.

The namespace will have values for both `day` and `fast` regardless of what is in the commandline.  If you want the `day` value to have priority of the `fast` one, choose the `defaults` so you can distinguish between the default and a given value.  The default default `None` is handy for that.

You could use `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` to keep a default out of the namespace, but that's harder to test than `args.fast is None`.

As discussed in [Python argparse --toggle --no-toggle flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735831/python-argparse-toggle-no-toggle-flag) your arguments could even share the `dest`.  Whether that makes the following logic easier or not is questionable.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Used const and default for "day" and just const for "fast". How did I miss it when reading manuals =)